# Highstocks is rounding all of my data

Tags: highcharts

Simply put Highstocks seems to be rounding all of the data that I put into it, I need up to two decimal places shown which I have set up in the tooltip however at the moment all I am receiving for the two places are 0's. So instead of 1.5 its 1.

```
$.getJSON('mkjson.php?device=<?echo $device_name;?>&sensor=<?echo $sensor_name;?>&pin=<?echo $pin;?>&user=<?echo $_SESSION['user'];?>', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {

            text : 'Device:<?echo $device_name;?>'
        },
        subtitle : {
            text : 'Sensor:<?echo $sensor_name;?>'

        },

        xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
            hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
            day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
            week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
            month: '%Y-%m',
            year: '%Y'
        }
    },

        yAxis : {
            title : {
                text : '<?echo $unit;?>'
            }


        },

        rangeSelector : {
            buttons : [{
                type : 'minute',
                count : 10,
                text : '10m'
            }, {
                type : 'hour',
                count : 1,
                text : '1H'
            }, {
                type : 'day',
                count : 1,
                text : '1D'
            },
            {
                type : 'day',
                count : 3,
                text : '3D'
            }],
            selected : 3,
            inputEnabled : false
        },          

        series : [{
            name : 'Voltage',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Show your JSON for a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can format numbers using `Highcharts.numberFormat()`.

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        }
```

> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/em7h6/

Btw according to this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/valuedecimals/

using `valueDecimals` should also work, don't know whats missing in your case.

Comment: I want the numbers to not be rounded, there is something in my code that is automatically rounding them. I don't think the tooltip is the issue.

Comment: This solution simply gives me more digits to use after the decimal but my issue is that its taking a value of 1.5 and turning it into 1.

Comment: can you try the example I gave by putting your data into data attribute. I don't see anything strange with your code.

Comment: Alright..... Thank you for the clarification it turns out it was being sent as an int instead of float >_> Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should works http://jsfiddle.net/rbr23/ without using numberFormat();

```
 chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.92, 71.51, 106.433, 129.12, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.61, 54.43]
        }]
```